# Problem with cropmarks on geometry package

Tags: geometry, paper-size, crop

I want to print a page with a smaller size than and A4 paper on a A4 size layout and I want to show the crop marks on it. I specify the page and layout size in the geometry package options but as you can see in the MWE, half of the page goes outside of the A4 paper. I am pretty sure I missing some options here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ layoutheight=297mm,layoutwidth=210mm,paperheight=197mm,paperwidth=130mm,showframe=true,showcrop=true]{geometry}
\usepackage[center,a4]{crop}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico I edited to show what I want. I want the smaller page to be centered in the middle of the A4 paper. But, as you can see, half of the page is gone outside of the A4 paper.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post a solution that uses the parameters `layoutvoffset` and `layouthoffset`.

Comment: @Mico thank you very much... I have been working on the problem for about six continuous hours!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the terminology of the `geometry` package, the `paper<*>` parameters refer to the physical size of the sheets of paper the document will be printed on. The `layout<*>` parameters, by contrast, refer to the logical size of the "paper", which will (one hopes) be no larger than the physical size of the sheet of paper. (Put differently, with regard to `paper` and `layout`, your terminology and that of the `geometry` package are exactly reversed...)

You will need to use the parameters `layoutvoffset` and `layouthoffset` to indicate *where* on the physical page the logical page is supposed to be placed. Assuming that the logical page should be *centered* on the physical page, and given that the differences between the physical and logical dimensions are 100mm and 80mm, respectively, the values of `layoutvoffset` and `layouthoffset` should be 50mm and 40mm.

By the way, if the logical page is supposed to be exactly centered on the physical page, you needn't load the `crop` package; specifying the option `showcrop=true` (as you already do) suffices.

*Addendum*, to address the follow-up request to make the text block margins be zero: To make the text block occupy the entire logical layout, while still showing the header and footer lines, you need to specify the options `margin=0pt` and `includeheadfoot` when loading the geometry package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[ paperheight  =297mm,paperwidth   =210mm,  % or: "paper=a4paper"
             layoutheight =197mm,layoutwidth  =130mm,
             layoutvoffset= 50mm,layouthoffset= 40mm,
             margin=0pt, includeheadfoot,
             showframe=true, showcrop=true]{geometry}

%% \usepackage[a4,center]{crop}  %% not needed if logical page is centered on physical page

\begin{document}
\chapter{In the Beginning}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know you can just say `layout=a4paper` and omit the `paperheight` ,`paperwidth` statements (but not the `layoutwidth=...` of course)... and you were just a few seconds quicker than me :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I chose this way to show the A4 paper size, because later it would be easier to shift from a portrait to landscape paper.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: The `landscape` option should help too... and the solution is bascially what I proposed to you yesterday evening in chat ;-)

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent - Note, incidentally, that I didn't specify any margin options, as you didn't specify any settings in that regard either. You will probably still need to set the top, bottom, left, and right margins -- unless, by some chance, you're satisfied with the default settings.

Comment: @Mico What's the reason for such distance between the crop sign and the corner of the logical page? Is it because of the margins not defined?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- Sorry... Did you mean to write `paper=a4paper`? I knew about that option, but I chose to show `paperheight` and `paperwidth` explicitly, because doing so makes it (more or less) obvious what the `layout[hv]offset` values need to be.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent - I didn't specify values for the text block margins since you hadn't provided any information in that regard. You can specify the margin settings just like you would in an "ordinary" document, i.e., one in which the physical and logical page dimensions coincide

Comment: @Mico... yes, sorry, I was in a hurry... `paper=a4paper` -- it will use the a4paper size then. Perhaps, the physical margins of the crop page should be calculated outside, but your version is fine!

Comment: @mico Could you please take a look at the edited question? I want the top margin cross the crop sign...

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent - To achieve the modified objective, just specify the options `margin=0in` and `includeheadfoot` when loading `geometry`.